# general solution using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that method of variation of parameters applied to the equation $y'' + y = f(x)$ leads to a particular solution $y(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \cdot \sin (x-t) dt$.
I tried like this 
Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is $1$.
Two solutions of corresponding homogeneous  DE are $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.Then put these values into formula used in variation of parameters.Bit i did not get answer.of this form.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/470317/8581) for help. (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this just involves some elementary functions simplifications.

By [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_variation_of_parameters), you can get the particular solution is $y_p=\sin x\int_0^xf(x)\cos x~dx-\cos x\int_0^xf(x)\sin x~dx$

Note that the particular solution can also rewrite as

$y_p=\sin x\int_0^xf(t)\cos t~dt-\cos x\int_0^xf(t)\sin t~dt$

$y_p=\int_0^xf(t)(\sin x\cos t-\cos x\sin t)~dt$

$y_p=\int_0^xf(t)\sin(x-t)~dt$